# drag and resize a shape in react-native

Tags: react-native, resize, shapes, drag

im new to react-native and overhelmed with all the options in the www. thats why i'm a bit confused how to complete this task in the best possible way.

i want to make something similar to [this](http://codepen.io/abruzzi/full/EpqaH/), but in react-native. A square-shape, which i can drag all over the view + resize it by dragging it's corners. I already took a look into exponent IDE and the given ThreeView-Component, but i think three.js is a bit over the top for this task, right?

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/abruzzi/pen/EpqaH
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 6):

`react-native-gesture-handler` is the most appropriate thing for your case. I have created minimal example in snack. Here is the minimal code:

```js
  let FlatItem = ({ item }) => {
  let translateX = new Animated.Value(0);
  let translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
  let height = new Animated.Value(20);
  let onGestureEvent = Animated.event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        translationX: translateX,
        translationY: translateY,
      },
    },
  ]);
  let onGestureTopEvent = Animated.event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        translationY: height,
      },
    },
  ]);
  let _lastOffset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let onHandlerStateChange = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      _lastOffset.x += event.nativeEvent.translationX;
      _lastOffset.y += event.nativeEvent.translationY;
      translateX.setOffset(_lastOffset.x);
      translateX.setValue(0);
      translateY.setOffset(_lastOffset.y);
      translateY.setValue(0);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onGestureTopEvent}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            widht: 10,
            height,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            transform: [{ translateX }, { translateY }],
          }}
        />
      </PanGestureHandler>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.item,
            { transform: [{ translateX }, { translateY }] },
          ]}>
          <Text>{item.id}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

let data = [
  { key: 1, id: 1 },
];
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatItem item={data[0]} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bungler/draggableexample) link if you want to test! PS: I have made only top resizing. The rest is for you to do! It should be enough to understand the way how to it!

Comment: Upvoted. It helped. But resizing is must be required.

Comment: I did include resizing as well!

Comment: Hi @OriHero Could please help me out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556614/animation-like-slack-comment-box-react-native